# PHP Exec() function not working in Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: php, windows-server-2003, exec, file-permissions

Could you please tell me how to run exec() command on windows server 2003 R2. I am trying to run Subversion executable file, but php keeps returning me empty array instead of output.
I have set up permissions for:

- cmd.exe
- system32 folder
- subversion/bin folder
- php folders

Please tell me what am I missing. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give us anything to go on. Try to configure your webserver to produce an error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your web server under a new user account (with admin permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Does something simple like `exec('dir')` work?

Comment: No... It only returns empty array.

Comment: I meant that $output returns empty array. I am sorry for lapsus.